# c++, how do I remove letters from a string inputed in console?

Tags: c++, string, character

I want to print on the screen a string without it's first letter, first 2 letters, first 3 letters etc. And then, without it's last letter, last two letters etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: Sounds like homework doesn't it.

Comment: You can use `std::string` object and call it's `substr` method.

Comment: Homework is not a problem if the person asking the question included their minimal code example (in text no pictures of text please) and explained the problem they are having with the code. Without a code example no one can help.

Comment: Well, it's not homework. 

At school they didn't say anything about string yet. And on internet i can't find a way to work with strings that you write in console.

Comment: @George then I will print without it's first letter after without it's last letter.

Comment: We can't give you any code before you show your code.

Comment: I general you remove letters from a string by copying or reading only a portion of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << input.substr(i) << std::endl;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << input.substr(0, input.size()-i) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](https://www.ideone.com/WHymo6)